# Changing the size of the area for page swiping in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have been trying to adjust the area where you drag the page in PageLayout in kivy.  I cant seem to find the parameter that controls this.  I am mostly doing all the editing in a .kv file rather than python as i am new to the game.  I want the user to be able to swipe from a halfway point along the x axis of the page to get to the next page.  I will attatch the code i have so far.

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    PageLayout:
        drag_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
        Image:
            source: r"C:\Users\16783\Desktop\Protocols app\pics\Meds\Dekalbprotocols (1)-236.jpg"
            allow_stretch: False
            keep_ratio: False

            size_hint: 1, 1
        Image:
            source: r"C:\Users\16783\Desktop\Protocols app\pics\Meds\Dekalbprotocols (1)-237.jpg"
            allow_stretch: False
            keep_ratio: False

            size_hint: 1, 1
```

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `border` property to specify the width of the sliding side like this

```py
#import window
#: import Window kivy.core.window.Window


BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    PageLayout:
        drag_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
        border :Window.width/2 # to be the half width of the screen
        Image:
            source: r"C:\Users\16783\Desktop\Protocols app\pics\Meds\Dekalbprotocols (1)-236.jpg"
            allow_stretch: False
            keep_ratio: False

            size_hint: 1, 1
        Image:
            source: r"C:\Users\16783\Desktop\Protocols app\pics\Meds\Dekalbprotocols (1)-237.jpg"
            allow_stretch: False
            keep_ratio: False

            size_hint: 1, 1
```

note that the `border` value is default to dp(50) as presented in the [doc](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.pagelayout.html)
the kv import is different from py import check this the [doc](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html)

Comment: Thank you for telling me about that parameter, I have tried to use the window class, and I have imported it from kivy.core But it is saying that it is undefined. Do you have any idea what that's about

Comment: you did not import Window in the correct way kv lang import is different from py import